# How to dot-dot from non-existent directory in Linux (dir1/non-existent-dir/./file)

Tags: linux, shell

Is there any way to dot-dot cd/ls/whatever if the path has an non-existent directory in it? Maybe there is some syntax to do so?

E.g. I need to cat the file `valid_dir/file.txt` but for some reason I can't to it directly.

```
$> cat valid_dir/non-existent-dir/../file.txt
```

Comment: `..` isn't a command; it's the name of a specific directory. `non-existent-dir` doesn't exist, so neither can `non-existent-dir/..`.

Comment: Thanks, yes, that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

In GNU Coreutils, there is [`realpath`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/realpath-invocation.html#realpath-invocation) to print resolved absolute filenames:

```sh
cat "$(realpath -m valid_dir/non-existent-dir/../file.txt)"
```

The `-m` (`--canonicalize-missing`) option is required if there are non-existing components.

If you want relative paths instead, you can define the directory they should be relative to with `--relative-to`, for example the current directory:

```sh
$ realpath --relative-to=. -m valid_dir/non-existent-dir/../file.txt
valid_dir/file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, realpath was new to me. Though the question is a bit trickier as I have access only to the path part itself (think of a security research of some tool that displays the given file based on its path) so I can manipulate only part of it

Comment: @slyweex Not sure I understand, is that something different from what the question asks for? Can you clarify? What's the "path part"?

Comment: @slyweex `realpath -m` also normalizes if none of the directories exist: `realpath --relative-to=. -m foo/bar/../baz` prints `foo/baz`, even if `foo` doesn't exist.

Comment: Sorry for messing this up :)
I have an application (or script) that takes an incoming parameter, say, `filename`. 
Somewhere in the app there is an instruction to print out the given file like `file_get_contents('dir1/dir2'.$filename);`
If I pass `filename = 'file.txt'` it wil make a path like `'dir1/dir2/file.txt'` and will open the file
But I want to open the file outside the intended path, so I pass `filename = '../../file.txt'` and the resulting canonical path should be just `'file.txt'`. 
The problem is that if `dir2` doesn't exist - this won't work just like it doesn't work in shell

Comment: @slyweex And do you have control over the app, or can you only supply the parameter? Is the app a shell script?

Comment: I can control only the `filename` parameter. Thus I am playing around with different combinations on how to traverse up the directory tree.

Comment: @slyweex There is no magic string that makes any other program normalize a path, which – if I understand you correctly – is what you'd like to have.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I wasn't sure and was looking for the confirmation :)